# Can't open some websites on OSX after moving overseas

Tags: macos, networking

I've moved overseas, with my Mac.  It is running 10.9.5

I can open some websites but not others, not even superuser.com  - enough websites won't open for me to be sure it is me, not them.  Enough do open to know I am connected to the internet.  Other computers connecting through the same network can open the problem sites.  All browsers and the software update function are having issues, so it isn't just a chrome or safari issue.

The error when a webpage won't open is "page took to long to respond"

How can i fix this?

Comment: What does your DNS settings look like?

Comment: If you use a VPN does the behavior change?

Comment: @tuananh - what DNS settings?

Comment: @Ramhound - i don't have a VPN

Comment: @Will - There exists free VPNs.  The point of the VPN is to determine if your ISP is filtering the content or if its a simple DNS problem.

Comment: I went into advanced network settings to check DNS, there is nothing in there.

Comment: @Ramhound it's not the isp, i can connect to the site's with my laptop no problem, same connection.  eg, i'm typing this on supercomputer on macbook, but next to me the desktop mac can't get to the site.  same wifi

Comment: Set the DNS to google or opendns, outside of that, perform ping, or trace on the route for those websites not working.

Comment: ok.  i tried opendns.  still doens't connect and ping says:  --- bbc.co.uk ping statistics ---
89 packets transmitted, 89 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 10.556/11.506/13.101/0.457 ms

Comment: What about other browsers on your Mac? If you use Firefox or Chrome - same problem?

Comment: Did you bring your wireless router (or other kind of home gateway/router/modem box) with you as well? Are you using it? If so, what DNS servers is *it* configured to use? What DNS server addresses is it configured to serve out via DHCP? Since your Mac can open *some* sites by name, it must be getting DNS server address settings from *somewhere* (i.e. DHCP, PPP[oE], IPv6 router advertisements, etc). I ask because some CDNs route you based on your DNS server, so if you're still using DNS servers from your previous country, you could be going to an overseas CDN node, causing timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

One rare-but-not-TOO-rare cause of "some sites open but others don't" is an MTU problem, such as a failure of the "Path MTU Discovery" algorithm (a.k.a. a "PMTU Discovery black hole").

As a test, try setting your MTU down to 1300 and see if all websites open. If so, then adjust your MTU higher until you find the maximum value that works.

From what I've seen, Google configures all their servers to use a smaller TCP MSS (Maximum Segment Size, the TCP-layer equivalent to the IP-layer's MTU concept) to make sure their sites load even for people with Path MTU Discovery black holes, so some people describe MTU problems as "Google sites load, but lots of other big-name sites don't".

Path MTU Discovery relies on:

1. All routers along the path between the client and the server must honor the "Don't Fragment" bit in the IP header, and send back an ICMP "Fragmentation Required, but "Don't Fragment" bit set" error message. I've seen bad routers that don't properly do this, and break PMTU discovery.
2. All routers/firewalls along the path must allow those ICMP messages to pass. I've seen ignorant firewall administrators block all ICMP because they wanted to block ping. They didn't realize that ping uses just one pair of ICMP message types (echo request/response) and that there are many other ICMP message types that are critical for proper operation of the Internet, that should not be blocked.
3. Any NAT gateways along the path must properly NAT-translate the ICMP messages so that they get back to the machine that sent the packet that was too big. I've seen bad NAT gateways that mishandle ICMP messages and break PMTU discovery.

Answer (score 0):

I get a lot of U.S. website non-responses accessing them from Argentina. I attribute this to a webmaster's thinking "This is not for your market, so I ain't wasting CPU cycles on you."

So what I do is access through a proxy server.